# How to return generator outputs

Tags: python-3.x, generator

I want to figure out how to return generator outputs. I know that `next(generator)` returns the yielded output of the function, but I want to know how to return multiple yielded outputs.

For instance:

```
alist = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
def aiterator():
    for i in alist:
        yield i+1

generator = aiterator()
```

I know that `next(generator)` will return 1, but how do I return 2,3, or if I want, 2,3,4 without typing `next(generator)` twice or three times?

Specifically, I'm thinking of another function which will return the number of `next(generator)`s:

```
for i in aiterator():
  return ?
```

Comment: generator always return each yield one by one with next tick, So if you want different output then you need to change yield value.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to output the whole list one by one, use:

```
while True:
  next(generator)
```

If you want more customized output, then as mentioned in one of the comments, change the `yield` value.

Comment: After the generator is exhausted, the `while` loop will break with `StopIteration` error.